Проблемы с импортами VK API в боте для ВК
Сделал бота для ВК, который будет из одной беседы пересылать их в другую, но он не работает, а в VS Code показываются 2 проблемы:

Import "vk_api" could not be resolved Pylance(report Missing imports) [Ln 1, Col 8]


A Import "vk_api.longpoll" could not be resolved Please(report Missing imports) [Ln 2, Col 6]

Не могу понять, что я сделал не так.
Вот сам код:
import vk_api from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventTypвведите сюда кодe

# Токен доступа вашего бота token = "-"

# ID беседы, из которой нужно пересылать сообщения source_chat_id = -

# ID беседы, в которую нужно пересылать сообщения target_chat_id = -

# Инициализация сессии VK vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token) vk = vk_session.get_api() longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send_message(chat_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=0  # Обязательно для отправки сообщений
    )

# Основная логика пересылки сообщений for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        if event.chat_id == source_chat_id:
            # Получение текста сообщения и его пересылка
            message_text = event.text
            send_message(target_chat_id, message_text)
            print(f"Сообщение переслано: {message_text}")


"Сделал бота для вк который будет из одной беседы пересылать их в другую" — "их" это кого, пользователей?

По ошибке видно, что у вас проблема с импортами, а не столько, сколько с самим кодом... Вот этот фрагмент что должен значить: "VkEventTypвведите сюда кодe"? У вас, случаем, так в самом коде не написано? Вы весь фрагмент импорта предоставили??

По поводу "VkEventTypвведите сюда кодe" — зря сказал, просто вы не доследили при вставке кода в текст вопроса. Для исправление поправьте ответ. Но вот по поводу импортов — вы точно предоставили всю строку?
